# Sets of compositions of homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking of a relation in the form:
$$
Hom(X,Z) = Hom(X,Y)\otimes Hom(Y,Z),
$$

or:
$$
Hom(X,Z) \subseteq Hom(X,Y)\otimes Hom(Y,Z),
$$

or similar (maybe it's not a tensor product? maybe the inclusion is in the other direction?),
where $X,Y,Z$ are vector spaces, and $Y$ has dimension large enough.

Is there such a relation?
Also, is there anything similar for groups or modules?

Thank you.

Comment: Defining suitable maps would be easier than $\subset$ or $=$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, composition of homomorphisms can be viewed as a map
$$ Hom(Y,Z)\otimes Hom(X,Y) \to Hom(X,Z).$$

This map is surjective if $Y$ has dimension large enough (namely, has dimension at least $\min(\dim X, \dim Z)$).  Thus $Hom(X,Z)$ is a *quotient* of $Hom(Y,Z)\otimes Hom(X,Y)$.

However, since we work with vector spaces, every surjection has a section.  In other words, there is an injection $Hom(X,Z) \to Hom(Y,Z)\otimes Hom(X,Y)$.  However, there is no canonical way to choose this injection.  One way to do it, though, is as follows: assume that $Y$ has dimension greater or equal to that of $X$. Let $i:X\to Y$ be an injection.  Then there is a surjective map $p:Y\to X$ such that $p\circ i = id_X$, and the map
$$Hom(X,Z) \to Hom(Y,Z)\otimes Hom(X,Y): f\mapsto (f\circ p)\otimes i$$
is injective.

The case where $Y$ has dimension larger that that of $Z$ (instead of $X$) can be dealt with in a similar way.

I don't see that there is a general way to deal with the case of modules or groups.